# Manejo de parametros usando text Search (google maps) en Androi

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-maps, google-api

Tengo una duda con la api de google maps (text Search), actualmente implemento un buscador de direcciones pero me tope con el problema que muestra resultados fuera de México (Zona donde quiero limitar las búsquedas), siguiendo la Doc.
[Doc. Google maps (text search)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text)

intento agregar los parametros pero no hay diferencia en la busqueda:

Donde params:

```
search = "holl"
radius = 10000
region = "mx" tambien probe "MX" (mismo resultado)

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=$search&radius=$radius&key=API_KEY&region=$region
```

De que forma puedo agregar la región para que limite los resultados solo a México y veo que tampoco me respeta el radio que agrego para las búsquedas.

[image: img_result]

La razón de usar text search es porque el usuario puede agregar direcciones ambiguas.

Comment: Buen día, puedes utilizar las opciones de `components` para filtrar por país `components=country:mx`. Avísame si te resulta para escribirlo en la respuesta

Comment: Buen día, lo intente utilizar sin embargo obtuve el mismo resultado, al final estoy usando una solución a medias, como el campo formatted_address tiene al final el pais al que pertenece, guardo en una lista los que tienen "México", creo que no es la mejor solución pero es un parche mientras busco algo mejor. Te agradezco la ayuda.